# Likelihood function-expectation

Tags: expected-value, likelihood, sample, parameterization

Given likelihood is a function of parameters, I cannot understand why the expectation of likelihood functions is not calculated with respect to the the parameter space but the sample space, as put here in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics)), '*the score is a function of $\theta$, it also depends on the observations at which the likelihood function is evaluated, in view of the random character of sampling one may take its expected value over the sample space*.' Because the parameters have a distribution as given by the likelihood function, though they may be deterministic in nature as determined by the principle assumed in likelihood applications, should this still mean that the parameter space should be used in the evaluation of the expectation of likelihood functions? I am sorry for the childish question, please help to clearify. Thanks.

Comment: First to integrate wrt the parameter, you need a probability measure over the parameter space. It does not exist outside Bayesian models, ie the only randomness is with $X$, the sample. Second, the likelihood $\ell$ is a random function in the sense that this function differs for each realisation of the random variable $X$, hence its distribution can be derived and its asymptotic behaviour (in the sample size going to infinity) studied.

Comment: Thanks, Xi'an, I am not able to fully grasp what you said here. I understand the randomness from the samples but because the integral cannot be done w.r.t. one space does not necessarily mean the result obtained based on another space is equivalent. It will be appreciated if you could provide more explanation or some relevant references, I am happy to do some exploration on my own based on your suggestions.